# imagemagickで様々な種類の画像を一括変換したい

Tags: 画像, imagemagick

フォルダ内にこのような画像がたくさんがあります。

123.jeg
abc.png
1a2b.gif
aaa.svg

変換後のファイル名が下記のようになるようにimagemagickを使用してWidgh800px、Height480pxでアスペクト比を維持したまま縮小し、imagesというフォルダの中に一括変換して保存したいです。

123.jpg.jpg
abc.png.jpg
1a2b.gif.jpg
aaa.svg.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagickは明示的にアスペクト比を無視する指定をしなければアスペクト比は維持されるので

```
mkdir -p images
find * -maxdepth 0 -type f -name '*' -exec convert {} -resize 800x480 images/{}.jpg \;
```

で変換されると思います。

厳密にするなら画像の拡張子だけをフィルタリングしたほうがいいでしょうが、フォルダ内には画像しかないものとして書いています。